# Test Class for 'return null': list has no rows for assignment to sObject

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

My Apex Class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static QCT_Claim__c getClaimInfo(Id claimId){
    return [select Id, Claim_Status__c, Requested_amount__c, Amount_type__c, Treated_amount__c, Gap__c, Accept_Gap__c 
            from QCT_Claim__c
            where Id = :claimId
            limit 1];
    return null;
}
```

My Test Class code for the return null:

```
    static testMethod void getClaimInfo_Test_Null(){

    Test.startTest();
    QCT_Claim__c testClaim = QCT_NoteInfoCtrl.getClaimInfo(null);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(null, testClaim);
}
```

How to test for the return null?  Doing it this way is getting me the error: list has no rows for assignment to sObject.

Answer (score 3):

You can't hit that line since you have an unconditional return before it. If you want to return a query result you're not sure exists, assign to a list.

```
List<QCT_Claim__c> candidates = [/*query*/];
return candidates.isEmpty() ? null : candidates[0];
```

If you leave the code as is (which you shouldn't; it's broken) then an exception *is* your expected behavior. You will not be able to cover that last line since it's impossible to hit. But you can verify "expected" behavior:

```
QueryException expectedException;
try
{
    QCT_NoteInfoCtrl.getClaimInfo(null);
}
catch (QueryException q)
{
    expectedException = q;
}

system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException,
    'Record should not be successfully queried');
```

Comment: That's a [ternary operator...](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) "This operator acts as a short-hand for if-then-else statements.

Comment: The problem is, i cannot modify the Apex Class code myself...i have been given the job to do only the test class...as for a ternary operator...thanks for the explanation @JohnThompson, but i knew about it ^^'

Comment: @varun you cannot hit that line. As for the error, you have to create the corresponding data.

Comment: That exception *is* the expected behavior as the code is written. It's poorly written code. You should push to fix it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson okay, thanks for the explanation :).  I will try to explain to the one who wrote the code.